# Advanced ListView control

Tags: listview, winapi, user-interface, autohotkey, win32gui

I am coding in Autohotkey language but this is a general question.
I am looking for a List view control that allows me to do something like this:

[image: List view showing photos + additional information]

I will be managing some products, The checkmarks show available products while X would show unavailable products. There would be some basic id and pricing information which is something that the default ListView control doesnt allow me to do in Icon View.

I do not have experience creating custom controls and while I would LOVE to learn how to do it I need this solution as quickly as possible and later on I will get on the task of creating my own.

Any information on this would be great!

PS: Please suggest me which tags are the best for this type of question.

Comment: There is no stock or common control in windows that looks like that; you would create your own.  IIRC AHK can implement an internet explorer host window, so HTML would be easiest.

Comment: Questions asking us to find or recommend a tool, library, product, book, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic here.

Comment: I have a simple tutorial explaining how to use CSS and HTML for your GUIs and how to set and get data from it. See: http://ahkscript.org/boards/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=4588